# Visual Studio. Using stacktrace's sequence as hit breakpoint condition

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I used hit breakpoint condition

```
(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(2) != null 
&& new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(2).GetMethod().Name 
== "UpdateFromLocationInfo")
```

I've checked this condition via quick watch  when hit this breakpoint "step by step" and it was true. But condition isn't working through f5 mode

Comment: As a workaround, you can just put that into an if statement, then put a non-conditional breakpoint inside the if statement. Obviously you'd want to revert that after you were done debugging

Comment: I don't need to use additional code. I just want to use visual studio instrument: `right click onto breakpoint, then choose "Condition..." in popup window`

Comment: I understand. I'm telling you a workaround if you can't get it to work the way you're trying to do it

Comment: @BenAaronson thanks! but it's not appropriate for my case

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to put conditional break point in the current method with you conditional expression your current method should be 'UpdateFromLocationInfo'. new on `StackTrace` always works on the current method where your newing object.

```
        // Create a StackTrace that captures filename, line number, and column 
        // information for the current thread.
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
            StackFrame[] stFrames = st.GetFrames();

            foreach (StackFrame sf in stFrames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sf.GetMethod());
            }
          //The StackFrame at array index 0 represents the most recent function call 
          // in the stack trace and the last 
          //frame pushed onto the call stack.
            if ((new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0) != null && 
            new  StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name == "UpdateFromLocationInfo"))
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }
```

You can see your output clearly by above procedure.